# How do i prove this is a metric?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory

> Define a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ in the following manner:
>
> > $d(x,y)=\min\{\frac{1}{n!} : n! \text{ divides } x-y \text{ where } n\in\mathbb{Z}^+ \}$ if $x\neq y$.
> >
> > $d(x,x)=0$
>
> Show that $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{Z}$

How do i prove that $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$?

I was trying to do this case by case, but i couldn't prove this..

Please help

Comment: $n! | x-z$ then $n!|(x-y)+(y-z)$ so, there are two options: or n! divides both that yields $\frac{1}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n!}$ or n! does not divide any of them..So if $m! | (x-y)$ then $m<n$ and the same for $k!|(y-z)$..so $\frac{1}{n!}\leq \frac{1}{m!}+\frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: Someone did while i was writing it :P

Comment: @user16117 Right.. Thank you :)

Comment: because if $m<n$ then $m!<n!$ then $\frac{1}{n!}<\frac{1}{m!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(x,y)+d(y,z)=\min\{\frac{1}{n!}:n!|(x-y)\}+\min\{\frac{1}{n!}:n!|(y-z)\}$

$d(x,z)=\min\{\frac{1}{n!}:n!|(x-z)\}$

$n!|(x-z)\Rightarrow n!|(x-y+y-z)\Rightarrow n!|(x-y)+(y-z)$

So either $n!|(x-y),n!|(y-z)$ or $n!$ divides neither, (since if it only divided one and not the other, it would not divide the whole)

If it divides both, then $\frac{1}{n!}\le\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n!}$

If $n!$ does not divide either, then there is $k!|(x-y)$ and $m!|(y-z)$, where both $m,k\le n\Rightarrow m!,k!\le n!\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n!}\le\frac{1}{m!},\frac{1}{k!}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n!}\le\frac{1}{m!}+\frac{1}{k!}$